# fill drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do i fill radio button list and drop downlist from database.

Answer (score 1):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31723w77(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

have a look at DataBinding and data boundable controls in MSDN. Your question like that it's so generic...

Answer (score 0):

Get the record from datasource in datatable or dataset and bind with dropdownlist. For example:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = your query to return data as datatable;

dropdownlist.DataSource = dt;
dropdownlist.DataBind();
```

or create a common function like:

```
public static void BindDropDownList(DataTable _dt, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList _ddl, bool IsDIndex,string text)
{
    try
    {
        _ddl.DataSource = _dt;
        _ddl.DataBind();

        if (IsDIndex == true)
        {
            _ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(text, "0"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        General.ErrorLog(ex.Message + " Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error, "General - BindDropDownList()");
    }
}
```